# Is "tx.origin" always an externally owned account (EOA)?

Tags: solidity, eoa, tx.origin

The Solidity docs on [Global Variables](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/cheatsheet.html?highlight=tx.origin#global-variables) say this about `tx.origin`:

> sender of the transaction (full call chain)

But that is a bit vague. Can we always be sure that `ts.origin` is an externally owned account (EOA)? Are there any edge cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is, `tx.origin` is the original sender of the call. In a transaction that results in a chain of calls, `tx.origin` is the EOA that initiated the transaction in the first place (contracts cant initiate transactions on their own) and `msg.sender` is the last member of the chain (and it can be a contract)

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans to let contracts execute txs on their own? I'm thinking of something like cron jobs.

Comment: Not that IK of. If you really need your contract to execute txs on its own you can set up something in web3.js that calls it periodically or in response to an event