# What type of eoa can meet the condition : tx.origin != msg.sender

Tags: smart-contract, eoa

```
modifier onlyEOA() {
   require(tx.origin == msg.sender, 'only EOA can call');
   _;
}
```

- I just read about **eoa check** with the above modifier, if the require true it completely fine, but the document said that :

> Addresses that do not match tx.origin can still be EOAs.

- So what **type of wallet** can do that?

Source : [EOA (Externally Owned Account) Checks](https://github.com/dragonfly-xyz/useful-solidity-patterns/tree/main/patterns/eoa-checks)

Comment: Where did you get this from: "even tx.origin != msg.sender, the address can still be eoa." 

I couldn't find it in the link you provided.

Comment: It in this section : tx.origin Check @Sky

Comment: just want to mention that I think in the future with account abstraction the EOA will be removed and contracts that limit access to eoa could not work anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "tx.origin" always an externally owned account (EOA)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109680/is-tx-origin-always-an-externally-owned-account-eoa)

Comment: I don't think so. The question is same energy but the answer just explains about order of calls chain.

Comment: I'd agree with @MajdTL , technically speaking `tx.origin != msg.sender` means that your direct caller is a smart contract, but with account abstraction coming this will probably change ( https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/account_abstraction_roadmap) , I think there is just confusion about the technical level distinction EOA vs CA and the more abstract one, where you could consider a multisig or any abstracted account as an EOA even though it is technically a CA.
I don't see any way to have `msg.sender != tx.origin` and msg.sender being an EOA, for the technical level, at least on Ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [EIP-3074](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3074) that would allow smart contracts to make calls on behalf of an EOA.

This could cause the `msg.sender` to be an EOA but different to `tx.origin`.

That EIP has not been implemented at the time of writing 1/2/24 but may be well added soon. Currently I don't believe it's possible on Ethereum Mainnet to have `tx.origin != msg.sender` for an EOA.

Answer (score 0):

GSN Lets the gas station pay the fee instead of your user who is sending the transaction. So msg.sender could provide an address value different than the one you should expect.

Comment: that does not explain why tx.origin != msg.sender :/ can you show an example or code